# Ignoring ItemId's gathered from notifications when manually syncing

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, exchangewebservices

How do I ignore ItemId's gathered from notifications?

Every time I receive new mail notification I add it to a list for the next round of syncing.

`_inBetweenProcessedItemIds.AddRange(notificationEventArgs.Events.OfType<ItemEvent>().Select(x => x.ItemId));`

However, it appears that even ignoring these ItemId's I still receive create events when manually syncing. Seeing as ItemId's get changed when the state of an email is modified (going from unread to read) how do I ignore an item as a whole?

Thank you.

Comment: Which notification model are you using (push, pull, streaming)? When you manually sync - you will get all previously notified emails. Why are you doing manual sync?

Comment: I sync manually every 30 minutes to ensure I don't miss any new emails. Say for what ever reason out Exchange server goes down. Once I reconnect I want to be able to fetch new emails I missed.